# How to get fixed object name for c3p0 mbeans object

Tags: java, spring, jmx, c3p0

I am using pooledDataSources in my application. ObjectName of Mbean for PooledDataSource contain variable part along with it. for example:

ObjectName = com.mchange.v2.c3p0:type=PooledDataSource[z8kfsx9c4bily2r1i962|23696a1b]

has variable as z8kfsx9c4bily2r1i962|23696a1b and it changes everytime i restart my service. I have to get fixed ObjectName for my mbean for monitoring purpose. I am using jmx for monitoring. I tried to override vmid property but it seems its a not writable property. Did a lot of research on this but running out of luck.

My Jmx Configuration is as following:

`<jmxtrans-agent>
    <queries>
        <!-- C3P0 -->
        <query objectName="com.mchange.v2.c3p0:type=PooledDataSource"   attribute="threadPoolNumTasksPending" resultAlias="cp.threadPoolNumTasksPending"/>
    </queries>
</jmxtrans-agent>`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, c3p0 JMX names look like this:

```
com.mchange.v2.c3p0:type=PooledDataSource,identityToken=<variable, opaque token>
```

In order to get a constant identifier, you must set ensure that the property `dataSourceName` is set. The best way to do that is to give your `DataSource` a name upon construction:

```
ComboPooledDataSource cpds = new ComboPooledDataSource("Jojo")
```

But you can also set `dataSourceName` like any other c3p0 config property.

Then you'll have JMX names that look like:

```
com.mchange.v2.c3p0:type=PooledDataSource,identityToken=<variable, opaque token>,name=Jojo
```

Many JMX clients let you search on attributes, so this is sufficient to give yourself a permanent monitor.

If you really need a constant, fixed, JMX name, you can set the property

```
com.mchange.v2.c3p0.management.ExcludeIdentityToken=true
```

This can go in a `c3p0.properties` file, as a System property, or as a HOCON/typesafe config path, depending how you are configuring c3p0. If you set this property and **also set** `dataSourceName` (again, via a constructor or in your config), then your JMX name will be a predictable, fixed String, like

```
com.mchange.v2.c3p0:type=PooledDataSource,name=Jojo
```

It will be up to you to ensure these names are unique.

Note: `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.management.ExcludeIdentityToken=true` is a new-ish feature, please be sure you are using the latest c3p0-0.9.5.1

For more details, see c3p0's [JMX configuration docs](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#jmx_configuration_and_management).

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I am setting dataSourceName property in my bean and m setting System.setProperty("com.mchange.v2.c3p0.management.ExcludeIdentityToken", "true"); but the mbean objectName is still coming with vmid. I tried setting property 'com.mchange.v2.c3p0.VMID' also to NONE but no luck with that also. But after upgrading the c3p0 version, m now atleast able to set the all these properties.

Comment: hi. don't bother with the VMID stuff. that won't help you. using System.setProperty(...) will be extremely fragile, as whether that has effect will depend upon the ordering of your call vs the loading of c3p0 config classes. if you want to set  c3p0 config in system properties, better to use -D<propname>=<propval> on VM startup. really, it's probably best just to make a c3p0.properties file and put it there (unless you are already using typesafe-config, in which case use that). i'm sorry if this is terse; i'm writing on a phone.